Dataframe to SQLAlchemy Update Statement Improvement
I created a method that updates a table called Trades from the content of a dataframe. Therefore I pass the index_cols (required for the where statement) and the update_cols (required for the set statement). The method then iterates through each row and then updates only one row inside the sql table (each row in the df represents a row in sql and thats why I have to iterate through the df).
The problem I have now is the following:

The update statement is rather slow, it takes a lot of time to update the values inside the table.
I tried different chunk sizes, but there was not really an improvement

Are there any improvement possibilities? Or are there best practices I didn't follow?
def update_trades_from_df(session_maker: sessionmaker, df: pd.DataFrame, index_cols: str | list[str],
                          update_cols: str | list[str] = None, chunk_size: int = 10000):
    if isinstance(index_cols, str):
        index_cols = [index_cols]

    if isinstance(update_cols, str):
        update_cols = [update_cols]

    valid_columns = Trades.__table__.columns.keys()
    if not update_cols:
        update_cols = [col for col in df.columns if col not in index_cols and col in valid_columns]

    with session_maker() as session:
        for chunk in chunk_using_generators(df, chunk_size):
            for idx, row in chunk.iterrows():
                filter_conditions = [getattr(Trades, col) == row[col] for col in index_cols]
                filter_condition = and_(*filter_conditions)
                values = {col: row[col] for col in update_cols}
                stmt = update(Trades).where(filter_condition).values(**values)
                session.execute(stmt)
            session.commit()


If you are in fact using MS SQL Server then this code might prove helpful.

That looks interesting! But I guess Ill need to change it so that it does update only not upsert. Thanks Ill look into it!

I have updated the gist so you can just call df_upsert( … , skip_inserts=True)

Thats an awesome script. I wanted to paste my solution which is is derived a little bit from your solution, but your script is adaptable.
